# Cross-origin image loading and manipulating

Tags: javascript, image, firefox, google-chrome, cors

I wrote a piece of javascript, stored on domain A, which is using CORS to enable me to embed it on a page from domain B yet still read data from domain A. I would also like it to fetch images from domain A and manipulate the pixel data using the html canvas. Normally, canvas.getImageData throws a security exception because I am not allowed to read the pixel data. Chrome allows me to do it (and supports the Image.crossOrigin attribute). However, Firefox and various other browsers do not.

Is there a workaround to load and manipulate the pixel data of an image from domain A in a script which is loaded from domain B?

Comment: is just embedding the image and reading the data directly from domain b an option?

Answer (score 2):

No, you just have to wait for other browsers to ship support for the crossorigin attribute.  In the case of Firefox that means waiting about a month.  For others, who knows...

Though actually... you could use cross-site XHR (which is somewhat better supported) to fetch the image data, build a data: URI from it, set an image's src to that data: URI, and then draw that image to the canvas.  That *might* work.